# CoreData crashes PersistentStoreCoordinator can't be created sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, crashlytics

On Friday i did an app update on the iOS app store. After some time some users reported crashes to me: the app crashes directly after start, but only for some people. i guess around 10-20% of the users are affected. I'm using fabric/crashlytics, here you can see the statistics:

---

[image]

---

My college gave me a iphone this morning which has also the bug. the main problem is not the save operation `saveContext:`, but that the persistantStoreCoordinator can not be created:

> Cocoa-Error 134130. reason=Can't find model for source store} with
>   userInfo dictionary { URL =
>   "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application//Documents/database.sqlite"}

In my opinion there can't be a database error alone because then every user would have this problem. some stackoverflow posts claim that error 134130 appears if you change an older model version. but i haven't and in my case this can't be the root of the problem, because then it won't work on that many devices. if you have an idea whats wrong, please tell me!

Comment: have you added or removed any core data fields from earlier version ?

Comment: These things happen even when they shouldn't. It is quite possible once you created a new built the core data was recompiled and messed it up so some devices have "incompatible" version on it. Sill no matter the reason you seem to be having a bad design so now your code is crashing. You need to handle these exceptions at all cost even if it means deleting the local database for the user. If that is unacceptable you best create a backup of the current database and a system for the user to send the file to you over email so you may repair it and somehow inject the data back to the sender.

Comment: If possible try to revert the current current build in the app store. It should be able to use the database which is still on the devices since you do not delete it in case of such error. Also save the conflicted database that was brought to you by your friend and try injecting it into your system. There might be a specific table or a field which produces an inconsistency so the users that did not use that part of the database have no issues.

Comment: @aman.sood no i haven't. i've looked through my svn commits and the last changes on core data fields were before the last version.

Comment: @MaticOblak yeah i know my design is not pretty and i will change it... until now i need a quick fix to get users happy ;) maybe creating a new data base is an oppertunity, i'll check that. i'll definitely save the data dase. thanks

Comment: You control the output path. What you currently have is probably checking if the file at that path exists, create a new one if it doesn't or use the same one if it does. You crash happens in the second scenario. A quick fix is to simply change this path so all new versions will have a deleted database while preserving the file that is already there. A bit better is to try using the same file and if it fails simply copy the current file to a new location (backup) and delete the current file and continue as if the file did not yet exist...

Answer (score 1):

Which I am guessing there might be a migration issue from your old build. Can you check if below parameter is passed

```
//****For  DB Migration
 NSDictionary *options = @{
                            NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                            NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES
                            };
```

in your code

`[_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]` as an options.

If not please add and check as this helps for light migration while app is update from current build to new build.

Reason which I can think for only 20% user facing this issue is they might have skipped last update and tried to update to new version you just released.

Comment: good guess, but those parameters are passed since the first version of the app.

Comment: Is it anywhere you are cleaning up data by deleting your database file ?

Comment: no i do not. i could find the error, see my answer. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I've found the issue after some hours: when i merged the model with SVN, there was a tiny commit missing. I've modified an `Integer 16` to `Integer 64`. So the previous model was really different than in the older app version, but i couldn't see it with SVN. Thanks for your comments anyway, it helped me finding the reason what went wrong!

The reason why only ~20% of the users were affected is, that only about 20% had some data in the core data entity which was affected (it containted some special configurations).